# Get data-attribute value with angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, custom-data-attribute

I'm trying to get the value of a data-attributes element in angular. I have my controller like this:

controller code:

```
(function() {

  'use strict';

  var app = angular.module('myApp');

  app.controller('globalCtrl', function ($scope) {

      var dataPreview = document.getElementsByClassName('element');


      $scope.item = {
        name: dataPreview.getAttribute("data-branch"),
        shortname: dataPreview.getAttribute("data-short-name")

      };

  });

}(window, window.angular));
```

But the console returns the following error:

**dataPreview.getAttribute is not a function**

I'm lost trying to find a solution to this error, can someone tell me what's wrong with my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate over the elements when you use class selector.

For eg:

```
var dataPreview = document.getElementsByClassName('element')[0];
// here 0 index element will be selected and then only you'll be able to use 
//  getAttribute method
```

If you use id, then you don't need to iterate:

```
var dataPreview = document.getElementById('element');
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I had forgotten that point ;)

Answer (score 0):

simple html tag with data attribute

```
<div class="branchUI" data-branch="some branch">I'm ok here</div>
```

I added class to button to get by querySelector, then get data attribute same as below

```
var branchUI = angular.element( document.querySelector( '.branchUI' ) );
console.log( branchUI.data( 'branch' ) );
```